# Can't run command with sudo, even with the full path, I got an error

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

The command `starling` is located at `/home/keating/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/starling`.

Only using `rvmsudo starling` will work properly. This is the result of me trying to invoke it in various other ways:

```
$ starling
Permission denied
$ sudo starling
sudo: starling: command not found
$ sudo /home/keating/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/starling
/home/keating/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find starling (>= 0) amongst [minitest-1.6.0, rake-0.8.7, rdoc-2.5.8] (Gem::LoadError)
from /home/keating/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
from /home/keating/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1229:in `gem'
from /home/keating/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/starling:18:in `<main>'
```

I really want to run the command with `sudo`, because the error above is the same as running `rvmsudo service starling start`(I had set starling as a service of the os).

Comment: Could be duplicate over at Stack Overflow: [How do you run or install starling under RVM?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670384/how-do-you-run-or-install-starling-under-rvm)

Comment: The question's not exactly a duplicate, but the solution is. The problem is that by default "sudo" will not call the program with the exact same environment you had as a user; rvmsudo preserves the relevant pieces, but the `service` command doesn't pass it on to upstart (it just instructs upstart to do something, so upstart's environment is relevant, not yours). Your solution is to provide the dependencies in the system or root default environment.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to popular belief, running `sudo` does not just run with elevated privileges, it runs at the user `root`. Your problem is that `starling` is installed locally to your profile, and `root` doesn't know that it exists. To fix this issue you need to add `starling` to your `PATH`.

In your case try this:

1. `sudo su -`
2. `PATH=$PATH:/home/keating/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/`
3. `export PATH`
4. `starling`

If that works, add that folder to your root path, then `sudo starling` should work. [Here is a good article about it.](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/prepostpath.htm)

Answer (score -1):

Become root with the command below:

> sudo su -

Answer (score -5):

Try this.

```
sudo passwd root
```

Now you can give in a password for root user. After which you can run:

```
su
```

Now you have elevated priviliges. Try running your app now...

Comment: For the sake of whatever you hold holy, no! There's a reason why there's no password set in Ubuntu by default, making the root-account available is *seldom* (if never) a solution.

Comment: You are right. SELDOM. Now it seems to be the case. I change it back whenever I am ready.

Comment: Wouldn't `sudo su` achieve the same?